# PHP / C Zend Module segmentation fault

Tags: php, c

I am developing a PHP Zend Module following these guides:

- [Zend PDF Guide](https://www.zend.com/sites/zend/files/pdfs/whitepaper-zend-php-extensions.pdf)
- [PHP Internals Book](https://www.phpinternalsbook.com/index.html)

I have followed the OOP example from the *Zend PDF Guide* (page 45) with few modifications to fit my requeriments.

```
#include "php.h"
#include "ext/standard/info.h"

#define DATABASE_MODELS_MODEL_TABLE_NAME "undefined"

static zend_class_entry *database_models_model_ce = NULL;

ZEND_BEGIN_ARG_INFO(arginfo_database_models_model_construct, 0)
    ZEND_ARG_INFO(0, properties)
ZEND_END_ARG_INFO()

PHP_METHOD(Model, __construct)
{
    /* Empty for now */
}

ZEND_BEGIN_ARG_INFO(arginfo_database_models_model_destruct, 0)
ZEND_END_ARG_INFO()

PHP_METHOD(Model, __destruct)
{
    zend_unset_property
    (
        Z_OBJCE_P(ZEND_THIS),
        ZEND_THIS,
        ZEND_STRL("id")
    );

    // Segmentation fault here
}

ZEND_BEGIN_ARG_WITH_RETURN_TYPE_INFO_EX(arginfo_database_models_model_get_id, 0, 0, IS_LONG, 0)
ZEND_END_ARG_INFO()

PHP_METHOD(Model, get_id)
{
    zval *zv, tmp;
    zend_long id;

    ZEND_PARSE_PARAMETERS_NONE();

    zv = zend_read_property
    (
        Z_OBJCE_P(ZEND_THIS),
        ZEND_THIS,
        ZEND_STRL("id"),
        0,
        &tmp
    );
    id = zval_get_long(zv);

    RETURN_LONG(id);

    // Segmentation fault here
}

ZEND_BEGIN_ARG_WITH_RETURN_TYPE_INFO_EX(arginfo_database_models_model_set_id, 0, 1, IS_VOID, 0)
    ZEND_ARG_TYPE_INFO(0, id, IS_LONG, 0)
ZEND_END_ARG_INFO()

PHP_METHOD(Model, set_id)
{
    zend_long id = 0;

    ZEND_PARSE_PARAMETERS_START(1, 1)
        Z_PARAM_LONG(id)
    ZEND_PARSE_PARAMETERS_END();

    if (ZEND_NUM_ARGS() > 0)
    {
        zend_update_property_long
        (
            Z_OBJCE_P(ZEND_THIS),
            ZEND_THIS,
            ZEND_STRL("id"),
            id
        );
    }

    // Segmentation fault here
}

static const zend_function_entry database_models_model_functions[] =
{
    PHP_ME(Model, __construct, arginfo_database_models_model_construct, ZEND_ACC_PUBLIC)
    PHP_ME(Model, __destruct, arginfo_database_models_model_destruct, ZEND_ACC_PUBLIC)
    PHP_ME(Model, get_id, arginfo_database_models_model_get_id, ZEND_ACC_PUBLIC)
    PHP_ME(Model, set_id, arginfo_database_models_model_set_id, ZEND_ACC_PUBLIC)
    PHP_FE_END
};

ZEND_RESULT_CODE database_models_model_minit()
{
    zend_class_entry ce;
    
    INIT_CLASS_ENTRY
    (
        ce,
        ZEND_NS_NAME("database\\models", "Model"),
        database_models_model_functions
    );
    
    database_models_model_ce = zend_register_internal_class(&ce);

    zend_declare_class_constant_string
    (
        database_models_model_ce,
        ZEND_STRL("TABLE_NAME"),
        DATABASE_MODELS_MODEL_TABLE_NAME
    );

    zend_declare_property_long
    (
        database_models_model_ce,
        ZEND_STRL("id"),
        0,
        ZEND_ACC_PROTECTED
    );

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

I get a segmentation fault on the get_id, set_id and __destruct methods. The only way to get it working is by commenting the `zend_update_property_long`, `zend_read_property` and `zend_unset_property` calls.

PHP Test program is:

```
<?php
    use database\models\Model;

    echo Model::TABLE_NAME . '\n';

    $model = new Model();

    // Works until here

    $model->set_id(123);
    echo $model->get_id() . '\n';
?>
```

Also I have tried changing the `Z_OBJCE_P(ZEND_THIS)` to `database_models_model_ce` and changing `ZEND_THIS` by `getThis()` but I get the same segmentation fault.

Thank you in advance.